# How to list only specific files from AWS S3 using amplify in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am working on a function that when the user presses to delete an object, it will get the associated pathway and delete it. Currently when that executes, the below function is called. Right now it is just listing all the values in the S3 bucket and I would only like it to list the specified values in accordance to the item I selected. I am not sure how to pass a parameter and return a specificed values in this method. Please advise. Next steps would be to then create a for loop to use this other function I have created that will remove each file.

```
 func ListModel(){

        Amplify.Storage.list { event in
            switch event {
            case let .success(listResult):
                print("Completed")
                listResult.items.forEach { item in
                    print("Key: \(item.key)")
                    
                    
                }
            case let .failure(storageError):
                print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
            }
        }
        
        
    }

func deleteImage(key: String){
    Amplify.Storage.remove(key: key) { event in
        switch event {
        case let .success(data):
            print("Completed: Deleted \(data)")
        case let .failure(storageError):
            print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not need to list the S3 bucket if you already know the key of the S3 object associated with the UI element that represents the object to be deleted.

Comment: Well I do not know the full path, so I need to get a list. The pathway is setup as UUID/DocID, so I just reference the path of the current user and the associated files within  DocID which are PNG, etc. So that needs to be the information deleted. Listing is why I need it @jarmod

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'pathway'. Is that Amplify terminology or your terminology? Anyhow, if you know the S3 prefix under which the object is stored then supply that when listing the bucket. There is no native S3 capability, or Amplify afaik, that will locate an object if you don't know its full key.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet as to how that would look for the above function I shared? I am having a tough time understanding. I appreciate your help

Comment: The point is that you are presumably already enumerating S3 objects so that you can show them in your UI. That should give you everything you need to identify an object (bucket & key).